# Why InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "ps" not recognized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using this code below;

plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

I get the following error message:  InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "ps" not recognized.

How can I resolve the error above?

Your kind response is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to Graphviz on Windows.
First install the following libraries;
pip install pydot
pip install graphviz
pip install pydot_ng

Graphviz plugins need to be registered before they can be used. In Windows, open the command prompt as admin and type dot -c to register. You can verify it by typing dot –v

If you encounter the following error:

C:\Users\ugoch>dot -c
Error: failed to open C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\config6 for write.

C:\Users\ugoch>dot -v
dot - graphviz version 2.44.1 (20200629.0846)

There is no layout engine support for "dot"
Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?

The next thing to do is to uninstall Graphviz from control panel and follow the steps below:

Visit the appropriate download location for your computer:

32-bit: https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/cmake/Release/Win32/65

64-bit: https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/cmake/Release/x64/896

1. Download and run the graphviz-install-VERSION.exe file.
2. Ignore any security warnings you might get.
3. During the installation, make sure you select “Add Graphviz top the system PATH for current user”.
4. When the installation is finished, start CMD as an administrator
5. Run dot -c in the Administrator: Console Prompt window.
6. Restart any applications or Command prompts where you want to use Graphviz.
   Try restarting your computer if you still have problems starting Graphviz.